# custom layer with Tensorflow 2.1 problem with the output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to have custom layer returning a tensor of (25,1) however there is a batch_size which should be passed through (I get an error from the next layer). I looked for examples, but could not figure how to specify the output shape.

Further I need an arbitrary output shape independent from the input size as the computation (not part of the below example) will always return a fixed number of values.

I tried the following:

```
class SimpleLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleLayer,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.baseline = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.1, trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        print ("in call inputs:", inputs.shape)
        ret = tf.zeros((25, 1)) + self.baseline
        print("Ret:", ret, "Shape", tf.shape(ret))
        return (ret)
```

this returns:

```
Ret: Tensor("om/add:0", shape=(25, 1), dtype=float32) Shape Tensor("om/Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
inputs (InputLayer)          [(None, 150, 1)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 150, 256)          512       
_________________________________________________________________
om (SimpleLayer)             (25, 1)                   1         
=================================================================
```

But this does make an output shape (25, 1) but not (None, 25, 1).

then I tried:

```
class SimpleLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleLayer,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.baseline = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.1, trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        print ("in call inputs:", inputs.shape)
        ret = tf.zeros((25, 1)) + self.baseline
        return (ret)
```

and got the error:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type 'NoneType' instead.
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the inputs data defined in the call methods otherwise the layer makes no sense

I provide a dummy example and works perfectly

```
class SimpleLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleLayer,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.baseline = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.1, trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        ret = inputs + self.baseline
        return (ret)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2])
```

create a model with SimpleLayer

```
inp = Input(shape=(25,1))
x = SimpleLayer()(inp)
out = Dense(3)(x)
model = Model(inp, out)
model.summary()
```

the summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        [(None, 25, 1)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
simple_layer_16 (SimpleLayer (None, 25, 1)             1         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 25, 3)             6         
=================================================================
Total params: 7
Trainable params: 7
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

**EDIT**

I try to override the problem of None dimension in this way

```
class SimpleLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleLayer,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.baseline = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.1, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64)

    def call(self, inputs):
        ret = tf.zeros((1, 25, 1), dtype=tf.float64) + self.baseline
        ret = tf.compat.v1.placeholder_with_default(ret, (None, 25, 1))
        return (ret)

inp = Input((150,1))
x = Dense(256)(inp)
x = SimpleLayer()(x)
x = Dense(10)(x)

model = Model(inp, x)
model.summary()
```

the summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_34 (InputLayer)        [(None, 150, 1)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_68 (Dense)             (None, 150, 256)          512       
_________________________________________________________________
simple_layer_9 (SimpleLayer) (None, 25, 1)             1         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_69 (Dense)             (None, 25, 10)            20        
=================================================================
Total params: 533
Trainable params: 533
Non-trainable params: 0
```